# Check if an element contains child with defined attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to check if my `Application` attribute have `Option` child with the name `Server` and `ServerPort`, same for `LDAP` attribute with `LDAPUsername` and `LDAPPassword`.

Here's sample of my code:

```
<MonitoringApplication>
  <Configuration>
    <Application>
      <Option name="Server" value="http://localhost" />
      <Option name="ServerPort" value="9000" />
    </Application>

    <LDAP>
      <Option name="LDAPUsername" value="azerty" />
      <Option name="LDAPPassword" value="password" />
    </LDAP>
  </Configuration>
</MonitoringApplication>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**XSD 1.0 cannot enforce such a constraint.**

Your options:

1. Redesign your XML:

   ```
   <MonitoringApplication>
     <Configuration>
       <Application>
         <Server>http://localhost</Server>
         <ServerPort>9000</ServerPort>
       </Application>

       <LDAP>
         <LDAPUsername>azerty</LDAPUsername>
         <LDAPPassword>password</LDAPPassword>
       </LDAP>
     </Configuration>
   </MonitoringApplication>
   ```

   You'll
     then trivially be able to express your constraints using basic
     content model terms.  You could even retain the `@value` attribute design; moving
     the `@name` attribute value to an element name is the most important part.
2. Check your constraint outside of XSD.
3. Use XSD 1.1 assertions.

**Option #1 is the right way to go from an XML design perspective.**